# Refactoring callback in express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express. I have multiple routers, segregated in different files -

```
router.post("/add", function (req, res, next) {
  if (isLoggedIn(req)) {
    nodeSdk.add(
      arg1, arg2,
      function (resp) {
        res.json(resp);
      }
    );
  }
});

router.post("/remove", function (req, res, next) {
  if (isLoggedIn(req)) {
    nodeSdk.remove(
      arg1, arg3,
      function (resp) {
        res.json(resp);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

I am passing same callback to nodeSdk in every router -

```
function(resp){
   res.json(resp);
}
```

Is it possible to refacor it out in a single file/place. I have too many routers, and everywhere this same callback is passed. Now I want to make the same change in every callback throughout the application. That is why I want to refactor so that in future if any change is there, it should be in one place. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you could just do it like this without manually creating a callback each time:

```
nodeSdk.remove(arg1, arg3, res.json.bind(res));
```

You could even create a middleware that runs before all your routes that automatically creates an already bound version of res.json:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.jsonB = res.json.bind(res);
  next();
});
```

And, then you can just do this in your route handler:

```
nodeSdk.remove(arg1, arg3, res.jsonB);
```

---

You could also create your own wrapper function to use as a substitute that does the `.bind()` for you:

```
function nodeSdkRun(res, verb, argA, argB) {
    return nodeSdk[verb](argA, argB, res.json.bind(res));
}
```

And, then use it like this:

```
router.post("/remove", function (req, res, next) {
  if (isLoggedIn(req)) {
    nodeSdkRun(res, "remove", arg1, arg3);
  } else {
    // must send some sort of response here
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});
```